# Mixing Class and Function templates

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, mixing

Hi I am trying to make a C++ class template and have it poses a function template too.. it boils down to

```
template <class T> 
class fun{
public:
    template<class U, class V> T add(U, V);
private:
    T data;};
```

I've have tried rewriting the signature in the cpp file (as opposed to the header file written above) many different ways. I'm starting to think that you can't have a class as a template AND have it have function templates as well.. Can you?

In the cpp file it looks like this and I get an error saying my declaration of the function "add" in the cpp file is incompatible with my declaration of "add" in the header file.

This is my function template in the cpp file.

```
template <class T, class U> T fun<T>::add(T a, U b){return a+b;}
```

Comment: You can't have a cpp file when using templates. Put it all in the header file.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You _can_ if you instantiate the versions you'd like to support in the cpp file explicitly (which sort of removes many of the benefits of using templates but sometimes makes sense).

Comment: You guys are awesome thanks so much!

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know man... I wrote that comment like 12 AM at night, and I was thinking "Oh, do I have to mention specializations? Maybe not... I think anyone reading my comment will know I'm talking about the specific example"... I was wrong :-) I do this all template specialization thing often to solve circular dependency problems.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist  There's always one :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class template definitions need to be known at compile-time to generate the class from the template, so the most common method is to include the definitions in the header file. If you still want to keep the interface and method definitions seperated you could use a `.tpp` file.

Here's a general approach, that creates a class from externally unique data types.

I.e. That you want `template <class U, class V> T fun<T>::add(U a, V b){return a+b;}` instead of `template <class T, class U> T fun<T>::add(T a, U b){return a+b;}`

header.h:

```
template <class T>
class fun{
public:
    template<class U, class V> T add(U, V);
private:
    T data;
};

#include "header.tpp"
```

header.tpp:

```
// out of class definition of fun<T>::add<U, V> 
template<class T> // for the enclosing class template
template<class U, class V> // for the member function template
T fun<T>::add(U a, V b) { return a + b; }
```

Comment: how do you do this with specialized classes and methods like fun<char>::add<int>?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a class template that includes a function template. Your problem is that you are trying to remove function definitions from header files. When you are using templates, you should include the function definitions in the header file. Note that you can practice such pattern only when you use template. Here is an example:

header.h

```
template <class T>
class fun{
public:
  template<class U, class V> T add(U u, V v) {
          return u + v;
  }
private:
  T data;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main () {
        fun<int> f;
        std::cout << f.add(10, 12) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @ChristianGalleisky If this answers your question, please mark it as an Answer. This helps others and encourages contributers